# How to get distinct values of Year level in MDX?

Tags: mdx, pentaho, cube, pentaho-data-integration, mdx-query

I have a cube Work with two dimensions :

1. Dimension Date with 3 levels : Day, month and year.
2. Dimension Task with 2 levels : Task A and Task B.
   I want to show tasks (A and B) by year, the problem is that when I execute my query I got duplicate values of the year. I tried using distinct but it didn't work.

Here is my query :

```
select {[Date].[Annee].Members} ON COLUMNS, {[Task][Task1].Members, [Task].[Task2].Members} ON ROWS from [Work]
```

And the result I got is :
[Execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id6fb.png)

Which is like doing : `Select [Date].[1].[1].[2014], [Date].[1].[1].[2015], [Date].[1].[2].[2014], [Date].[1].[2].[2015]`  and so on

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDsLX.png)

Where the first 1 is the day and the second 1 is the month, it returns results for years of every month and day. That's why I got duplicate years but I can't find how to resolve it.

I just want the results to be more general, I want to have values of tasks done by year.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Usually you’d have a simple year hierarchy in the cube so you could query like this:

```
SELECT
  {[Date].[Annee].[Annee].Members} ON COLUMNS, 
  {[Task][Task1].Members, [Task].[Task2].Members} ON ROWS
 FROM [Work]
```